# I don't see my implicit casting

Tags: python, numpy, casting, deprecation-warning

I have the following method:

```
def unify_np_array(A):
    '''Set every nonzero element in a numpy array to 1'''
    nonzero = A > 0
    A[nonzero] /= A[nonzero]
    return A
```

Which I call with the following test code:

```
def test_small_np(self):
    r = np.array([[3, 0], [0, 2]])
    DataConverter.unify_np_array(r)
    e = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(r, e)
```

The unit test succeeds, but I receive the following Warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds. 
In a future numpy release, this will raise an error. 
Use casting="unsafe" if this is intentional.
  A[nonzero] /= A[nonzero]
```

However, I don't see which incompatible kinds I am casting. I divide a subsection of a numpy array with itself. Can anyone pinpoint the cast I am implicitly making?

Comment: What is your numpy and python versions? I don't get the warning when running this code.

Comment: I am using Python 3.4 and Numpy 1.9.0.

Comment: Nope, those versions don't raise any warnings with your code for me.  Can you add a test to check that the output array `r` is integer after the `unify_np_array` function is applied? I was thinking maybe casting to float might happen, but it doesn't.

Comment: Both before and after the call to `unify_np_array`, `r` is a numpy.ndarray with dtype=int64. This is also the case for any moment time in the function `unify_np_array`.

Comment: Also not getting the error here (Python3.4, Numpy 1.9.2), but aside from the warning, why not just `A[nonzero] = 1`? Unless you've merely added this as an example.

Comment: Oliver, that is a stroke of genius! :-D